# How grant permissions a file to the caller of my COM object made in C#

Tags: c#, com, acl

I have a C# COM object that creates a file and returns the name of the file to the caller. Due to restrictions on the file system I have no control over, I need the COM object to grant read/write permissions for the file to the caller of the method. I can't just grant read/write to EVERYONE. Only the caller should be able to access the file. How do I get the security token of the caller of my COM object so I can then use that token to grant permissions to the file?

This is not running inside a service. There's no HTTP components. And the calling program is written in C++ so I don't have access to assembly information. None of these implementation details can be changed.

TL;DR: C++ program instantiates a COM object written in C# and calls a method. The C# method creates a file, grants permission to the caller's ACL to the file, and returns the file's name/path to the caller. The caller should now be able to access the file. How do I get the caller's ACL?

Comment: Is the COM object in-process (.dll) or out-of-process (.exe)?

Comment: DLL. In-process

Comment: if COM object is in-process, it's running under the same user of calling program

Comment: Indeed, in this case (unless doing very special things), the C# code and the calling C++ code are running under the same security context. So the callee ACL and the caller ACL are identical.